# how to change timeout values in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

i have setup a kubernetes cluster with 3 masters and multiple workers (kubeadm)
if i shut down a worker the node goes into Not-ready state fairly quickly but it takes some time for pods assigned to that node to be rescheduled
how can i decrease the timeout values to make my cluster react faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make it faster. A lot of actions are supposed to be done by Kubernetes to restart pods from a failed node.
However, it is possible to enhance reaction time.

For example, reduce the value of node-monitor-grace-period, default is 40 seconds.
It can decrease time between actual fail of a node and changing of its status.

You can find more details about these options [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/)